# VTK: Alternative to matlabs imfill

Tags: image-processing, vtk

is there any alternative method in VTK, similliar to matlabs
image-processing toolboxes method  [Imfill](https://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html)?

Comment: anything wrong with the VTK documentation? you should name what exactly you want to achieve not for any similar stuff...

Comment: Fill holes in volumetric image, like matlabs image processing method imfill. And couldn't seem to find similliar method in VTK documentation,thats why i'm asking.

Comment: and what's wrong about the results google gives you for "vtk fill holes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, VTK has been designed mostly for visualisation. For image processing, there is a complement framework, ITK (Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit), also maintained by Kitware.

I would like to suggest you to extend your project with ITK. Design of both class is very similar and if you have an experience with the former, you will adapt to the latter without any troubles. You can connect their pipelines simply just with `itk::ImageToVTKImageFilter` and `itk::VTKImageToImageFilter`. Then you can use  `itk::BinaryFillholeImageFilter`.